# Using onClick to click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="button"  
       onclick="restartBattle('Battle=Trainer&amp;BattleID=294','dtjuzULwzn')"  
       value="Restart Battle" 
       style="width:160px;">
```

How would I click this? I have this, but it's not working.

```
var btn = document.querySelector('input[value="Restart Battle"]');
  if (btn) {
        var x = Math.round((Math.random() * 90) + 663);
        var y = Math.round((Math.random() * 15) + 589);
    //btn.click();
  }
```

The 'dtjuzULwzn' that you see is the restartCode for the button, which is required to restart the battle.

If you need the source code for the page I'm making the script for, here you go. - 
http://pastebin.com/ZHfDnWdG

Here's my full code:
http://pastebin.com/0dE7quAB

Comment: You can't have those <br>'s in your JavaScript.

Comment: I know that, I did that to post it on here, that's all.
http://prntscr.com/3jd4s4
That's my coding before I posted here. I know that you can't have the <br>s in the coding.

Comment: Why raise an proxy UI event, when you can simply call `restartBattle` where required in your JS?

Comment: No idea I could do that, if I knew, I'd have done it. :c No idea where I'd put it or how I'd structure it either. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you accept jQuery answers as you have tagged jQuery.

Clicking an input button is as easy as follows:

```
$("input[value='Restart Battle']").click();
```

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zvx2/).

Comment: Yeah, the document fully loads then the code executes.

Comment: try calling it in the console?

Comment: Nope, no idea how to do that. xD

Comment: ohhhh, that! Gotcha, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: please make sure the button actually exists when you call.
and how about `$("input[onclick^=restartBattle]").click();`?

Comment: The button did exist when I called it. It pressed the button, but the pokemons HP didn't deplete at all, which means something didn't work.
Giving this one a try, hold on.

Comment: and please note that there are 2 functions with the same name restartBattle(). Only the last-defined function will be called. This is also a possible source of error.

Comment: I actually didn't notice that.. o.o